# Open Oracle Apex URL with JavaScript when giving parameters

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

when i use javascript `eval()` to open apex url from js i have no problem when i use `eval()` like this

```
 eval("f?p=&APP_ID.:7:&SESSION.");
```

but when i wanna pass parameters with `eval()` like this

```
eval("f?p=&APP_ID.:7:&`SESSION.:P7_ID:8461,P7_ALLOWCHANGE:1,P7_WFDEF_ID:69004.");`
```

i get this error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'`

then these parameters automatically added after generating url

```
javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=101:7:28809985622510:::::\u0026p_dialog_cs=_7P7TVFV5LTQPjeyg-bGqSKpcYM',{title:'Workflow State',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:true,dialog:null},'t-Dialog-page--standard '+'',this);:P7_ID:8461,P7_ALLOWCHANGE:1,P7_WFDEF_ID:69004.;
```

what should i do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03018 . Make sure this format is being followed.. The pre generated URL you have is  not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would to be to use apex_page.get_url
It is so much simpler to use than apex_util.prepare_url

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_page.htm#AEAPI30190

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your `eval` call, but this APEX URL syntax is wrong:

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:7:&`SESSION.:P7_ID:8461,P7_ALLOWCHANGE:1,P7_WFDEF_ID:69004.
```

All the item names should be listed together, then all the values together - and after the correct number of colon separators:

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:7:&SESSION.::::P7_ID,P7_ALLOWCHANGE,P7_WFDEF_ID:8461,1,69004
```

I also removed the spurious back-tick character from before "SESSION".

Comment: ty its not working .so how i can call modal dialog page in apex from js with pass parameters in url?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Tony Andrews covered, here are a few more issues with your URL:
1. it's APP_SESSION - not SESSION. Here's documentation on [built in substitution strings](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03024).
2. Your items are not substituted properly. Read this [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03022) more details on substitutions in APEX.

Here's [documentation on understanding APEX URL syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-url-syntax.htm#HTMDB03020).

Secondly, here's what you would try. Create a hidden page item and use APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL function and generate valid url, assign to the item. And use that item as url in your javascript. I haven't tried this, but this would be a better approach, I think.

Also prepare url like this:

APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL('f?p=' || :APP_ID ||':7:' || :APP_SESSION || :::' ||:P7_ID: ',' || :P7_ALLOWCHANGE || ',' || :P7_WFDEF_ID || ':8461,1,69004')

Here's another great resource to understand apex url and how to pass variables: 
http://dgielis.blogspot.in/2015/01/understanding-apex-url-passing.html